# Issues with Google Play Game Services occupying Android Res folder & Web API alternative?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

So we're in the middle of development of our Unity based game for Android. We had Facebook authentication already implemented and this makes use of the Android/Res folder. It stores some values and images there.

While trying to implement Google Play SDK for Authentication, Leaderboards, Achievements.... we came to realize it too makes use of the Android/Res folder which apparently causes a crash and not currently possible.

We're curious about 2 options

1) is there any possible way to allow 2 different services to make use of the Android resource system? Please note we're using Unity, and the plugin is made by Prime31.

If the source for the library is released then it could be possible to modify so the resource folder isn't used.

2) If we're stuck not being able to have Facebook and Google Play Services co-exist then is the entire process possible via REST JSON access? How is the Google+ sign in performed with our app launching a browser or Google+ app to securely take in credentials?

See our error log below

```
W/PopupManager(11358): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.W/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1994 (common_google_play_services_install_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

D/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0041

W/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1990 (common_google_play_services_enable_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

D/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x004c

W/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: unable to resolve static field 2000 (common_google_play_services_update_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

D/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0057

W/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1997 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

D/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0069

W/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1991 (common_google_play_services_install_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

D/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0009

W/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1988 (common_google_play_services_enable_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

D/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0010

W/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1998 (common_google_play_services_update_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

D/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0017

W/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1995 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;

D/dalvikvm(11358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0004

I/dalvikvm(11358): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x07c9 at 0x18 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b

I/dalvikvm(11358): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x07c8 at 0x38 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b

I/dalvikvm(11358): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x07c5 at 0x3f in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b

I/dalvikvm(11358): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x07cf at 0x46 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b

I/dalvikvm(11358): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x07cc at 0x66 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b

D/Prime31 (11358): onConnectionFailed: result 4

D/Prime31 (11358): onConnectionFailed: since user didn't initiate sign-in, failing now.

D/dalvikvm(11358): GC_CONCURRENT freed 430K, 5% free 9477K/9936K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 27ms

I/Unity   (11358): authenticationFailedEvent: Unknown error

I/Unity   (11358): 

I/Unity   (11358): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)

I/Unity   (11358):

E/Prime31 (11358): Exception running command on UI thread: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.

D/dalvikvm(11358): GC_CONCURRENT freed 385K, 5% free 9477K/9936K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 27ms

D/dalvikvm( 6765): GC_CONCURRENT freed 417K, 7% free 9483K/10172K, paused 7ms+2ms, total 32ms

E/Prime31 (11358): Exception running command on UI thread: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.

D/dalvikvm(11358): GC_CONCURRENT freed 385K, 5% free 9478K/9936K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 29ms

D/dalvikvm(11358): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 5% free 9478K/9936K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 62ms

D/Prime31 (11358): isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0

D/Prime31 (11358): beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.

D/Prime31 (11358): resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{423c8fe8: android.os.BinderProxy@423c8f88}}

D/Prime31 (11358): --------------------- result has resolution. Starting it. --------------------

I/ActivityManager(  506): START u0 {cmp=com.phyken.wizardopstactics/com.prime31.PlayServicesProxyActivity} from pid 11358

D/dalvikvm(11358): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 5% free 9481K/9936K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 80ms
```

Answer (score 0):

1) There isn't any problem in two services using the resources folder. All the resources will be on the final APK, just pay attention on the resources names so they don't conflict. The best practice is to use a suffix (example: fb_logo.png and google_logo.png, instead of two logo.png images)

2) Not needed!

If you posted the error log it would have been easier to help and point the exact issue!

Comment: Hi thiagolr there do seem to prefixes already on many of the files. there are some string.xml files which it seems would have to be manually merged.  Also I've added I believe the logcat from the particular error. I've heard this one user of res folder could be a limitation of Unity3D but unsure. Option 2 was my last resort and i guess a way to make the game code base truly cross platform.

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually merge the strings.xml files, this should work automatically!